# How to execute shell from Active Choices Plugin groovy script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to render information obtained from the shell in an active Active Choices parameter with a groovy script.  I can easily access the shell from a groovy script in a jenkins pipeline with the sh method like this:

```
node()
{
   sh 'git log ...'
}
```

But when I try this in the groovy script of Active choices, it crashes and the fallback script is executed.

Is it possible to switch to a node in this context and execute a shell command ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is sample snippet using the active choice plugin.

```
def command = $/aws ec2 describe-instances \
               --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=Test \
               --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].PrivateIpAddress \
               --output text /$
def proc = command.execute()
proc.waitFor()              

def output = proc.in.text
def exitcode= proc.exitValue()
def error = proc.err.text

if (error) {
    println "Std Err: ${error}"
    println "Process exit code: ${exitcode}"
    return exitcode
}

//println output.split()
return output.tokenize()
```

Comment: Not working for me for this command: `grep something ~/path/file | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d] -f1`

Comment: Snippet of gold. I needed to fetch a remote file list and populate the active choice plugin. Changed the cmd to ```def command = ['/bin/sh',  '-c',  'ssh user@host \'find /tmp/files/*pattern* \' ']```

Comment: Saved the day. Thank you

Comment: where do you see these println lines if this is part of the active choice parameter script property?  it seems the proc.waitFor() is problematic fo me.  if i remove it my script works. without it my script does not work.

Comment: @mike01010 it's been 2 years since I used the answer. But if memory serves me well, I had used it to change consecutive dropdowns to visualize a tree of options on a single UI. So what `return output.tokenize()` returns should be a list. Notice return is to UI element, whereas println is for debugging with logs. About `proc.waitFor()`, without it, following lines of code would immediately execute (without waiting background process to finish) and just return empty list. But after 2 years, take my word with a grain of salt.